# Выполнить табулировании функции

Tags: c++

шаг параметра = 1, шаг аргумента = 0.1

```
Y=(1-x)^2-A*exp(x)  0.5< =x <= 2   1 <= A <= 3
```

Текст программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    double x,y, ymax,xmax;
    for(A=1;A<=3;A++)
    {
        ymax=y=(1-x)^2-A*exp(x); xmax=1;

        for(x=1;x<=2.01;x+=0.1);
        {
            y=(1-x)^2-A*exp(x);
            printf("x=4.1; y=%7.2\n",x,y);
            if(y>ymax);
            {
                ymax=y;
                xmax=x;
            }
        }
        printf("****************\n");
        printf("\n ymax=%7.2f\n",ymax);
        printf("\n xmax=%4.2f",xmax);
        printf("=================\n");
        printf("для продолжения -");
        printf("нажать любую клав.\n");
        getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: На каком этапе у вас возникли сложности ?

Comment: на этом 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
 double x,y, ymax,xmax;
 for(A=1;A<=3;A++)
 {
  ymax=y=(1-x)^2-A*exp(x);
  xmax=1;

  for(x=1;x<=2.01;x+=0.1);
  {
   y=(1-x)^2-A*exp(x);

   printf("x=4.1; y=%7.2\n",x,y);

   if(y>ymax);

   {
    ymax=y;
    xmax=x;
   }

  }

   printf("****************\n");
   printf("\n ymax=%7.2f\n",ymax);
   printf("\n xmax=%4.2f",xmax);
   printf("=================\n");
   printf("для продолжения -");
   printf("нажать любую клав.\n");
   getch();
 }
}

Comment: Добавил текст в вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, у вас тут гора проблем.

- Переменная `A` незадекларирована (как оно у вас работает?).
- Первое вычисление `ymax=y=...` производится с неинициализированным `х`.
- Точка с запятой после условия `for` и `if`! Она «отменяет» цикл и условие.
- `^2` в C означает не возведение в квадрат, а исключающее или с константой 2.
- `printf("x=4.1; y=%7.2\n",x,y);` не содержит спецификаторов формата для `x` и `y`.

Наверное, ещё какие-то есть, но этих с головой хватает.

Comment: Внезапная слава: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3181/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ага, прилетели внезапные +40. А ещё _исчез_ соседний ответ легендарного по стилю изложения участника.